# why when i create a void method for onLongClickListener gives me this error in android studio?

Tags: java, android, boolean, void, onlongclicklistener

why when i create a void method for onLongClickListener gives me this error in android studio?
Error =>

```
'onLongClick(View)' in 'Anonymous class derived from android.view.View.OnLongClickListener' clashes with 'onLongClick(View)' in 'android.view.View.OnLongClickListener'; attempting to use incompatible return type
```

my code is :

```
    myBTN.setOnLongClickListener(
            new Button.OnLongClickListener(){
                public void onLongClick(View v){
                    TextView lblm=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
                    lblm.setText("Good Bye :| ");
                }
            }
    );
```

but when i use a boolean method ,there aren't error

```
    myBTN.setOnLongClickListener(
            new Button.OnLongClickListener(){
                public boolean onLongClick(View v){
                    TextView lblm=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
                    lblm.setText("Good Bye :| ");
                    return true;
                }
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

This method is already declared boolean by the team who wrote this code, you can only override the implementation, but not the return type, search for "method overriding"

Answer (score 0):

The interface [`android.view.View.OnLongClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html) has an [`onClick(View)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html#onLongClick(android.view.View)) method that returns a `boolean`. Since you can't overload methods by their return value, defining a method with the same argument list but with a different return type will cause a compilation error.

Answer (score 0):

It's the basic concept of method overriding.You can override a method by changing it return type.Method overriding work if the child class has same method signature as that of the parent.Here the parent is `Button.OnLongClickListener` which is an interface having the method defines as

```
interface Button.OnLongClickListener{

     public void onLongClick(View v);         

}
```

So you implementing anonymous class should also have the same signature.

Answer (score 0):

**Button** can not have **setOnLongClickListener** you are supposed to implement the **setOnLongClickListener** as **Button**,  based on **View.class** and **View.class** have an interface called **onLongClickListener** that have a method with the **boolean** type so you can always implement the **setOnLongClickListener** type as below:

```
button.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                // your code here
                return false;
            }
    });
```

you can checkout more **View.class** in android studio just clicked **OnLongClickListener** hope this help..